# How to select an element from a drop down list inside 'svg viewbox' container using Java/WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; fill: rgb(224,    224, 224); height: 24px; width: 24px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 14px; -webkit-user-select: none;"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg>
```

You can find the page at:
apply.autogravity.com. The page doesn't use the typical 'select' element found on other websites.
Any help would be great.

Comment: FYI: I've attempted using the select method and can't capture anything. I've also attempted the container option, but i can't capture anything since, the drop down options are not inside the svg view box element. I can only get so far as to click the drop down arrow, but i cannot get it to hover to any value as well.

Comment: where is your code? what exception(s) did you get?

Comment: I don't get exception, it just cannot find the elements. Here is a sample:            Actions move = new Actions(instance);
  move.moveToElement(di().findElement(By.("Honda"))).click().build();  this is my move mouse to method

Comment: The dropdown names like 'Honda' are being saved as 'div' elements. i attempted to read the page source and find the div, but it doesn't find it either

Comment: Pls accept the most helpful answer, So question will not be in Active queue for long

Answer (score 1):

> **Note  : For the select dropdown , HTML page should have `<select>` and `<option>` tag element.**

---

### Solution  :

As part of answer, to find element `<svg>` , Best xapth is this:

```
//div[@id='make-select']//button/div/*
```

---

### Approach to Select Car :

> **For select car from the dropdown, you can use tradition way to select your element :**

*Step 1 : Click on dropdown first* :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("make-select")).click();
```

*Step 2 : Select Car from the dropw down. Just pass your car name as parameter* :

```
String strCar = "Nissan"; 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@itemprop='itemListElement']//div[text()='"+strCar+"']")).click();
```

**Note : Put some sleep or wait between two click events for flawless script.**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
WebElement listbox_webelement =
drive.findElement(By.xpath("write_your_xpath_of_element"));


listbox_webelement.click() [ Expected to list get visible ]



   Select select = new Select(listbox_webelement);


   select.sendKeys("Text_From_Your_Listbox");
                  OR


   listbox_webelement.sendKeys("Text_From_Your_Listbox");
```