# How to Select drop down element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

Hi, I am trying to select item from dropdown. but I am unable to select . Please suggest me which tag I will use for select dropdown element.

Comment: Great, You have id in HTML. Would be easy. Give a try - I have answered on http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/21950/how-do-i-select-an-element-from-a-drop-down-list-using-java-webdriver-the-drop

Comment: Drop down list open but does not select. have any solution ?

Comment: Can you provide more information like the language being used for Selenium?

Answer (score 3):

The drop-down list is a select node with this id: operator_type

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("operator_type"))).selectByVisibleText("your desired type");
```

you should import: import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code this POM design pattern..

```
@FindBy(id="status")
WebElement status_dropdown;

public void select_List(String status)

    {
        Select statusdropdown=new Select(status_dropdown);
        statusdropdown.selectByVisibleText(status);
    }

    client.select_List("active");
```