# How to select from the dropdown list in PageFactory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects

The dropdown list is triggered by an input field. Once the dropdown list is shown, I wanted to select the item based on the index. When I am using `PageFactory`, (`@FindBy`) to identify the `WebElement`, there is always the `NullPointerException` error.

My question is, is there a (not complicated) way for me to use Select in PageFactory?

Comment: i feel this is not a dropdown , but suggested list using ajax call for input box, can you share your code, screenshot of input box and html code?

Comment: Try http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/21950/how-to-select-an-element-from-a-drop-down-list-inside-svg-viewbox-container-us I guess - you need to replace element by driver.pagefactoryWebElement

Answer (score 2):

Add a simple wrapper accessor around the `WebElement` accessor, like this:

```
@FindBy(id="dropdown")
WebElement dropdownList;

public Select getSelectOptions() {
  return new Select(dropdownList);
}
```

You can add helpful getter and setter methods too, like

```
public void setOption(int value)
{
  getSelectOptions().selectByIndex(value);
}

public String getSelectedOption()
{
    return getSelectOptions().getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
}
```

Using the following way we can use `Select` in `Page Factory`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle items inside a dropdown , Your drop down object should be looks like this.
It should be a `IList<IWebElement>` type

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "<XXXX>")]
 public IList<IWebElement> DropDown { get; set; }
```

After that using a for each loop go thru each and every item at the DropDown list.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Select class of Selenium Webdriver.

```
Select select = new Select(driver);
select.selectByIndex(<index-of-element>);
```